# Evaluate this integral without knowing the function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm an high-speed aerodynamics student but have some problems with some math expressions.

We know that: $$\int_0^c\dfrac{\partial z_e(x)}{\partial x}dx=z_e(c)-z_e(0)$$

I'm having trouble to do such a thing with the integral: $$\int_0^c\left(\dfrac{\partial z_e(x)}{\partial x}\right)^2dx$$

Or in a more general form: $$\int_0^c\left(\dfrac{\partial z_e(x)}{\partial x}\right)^ndx \quad | \quad n=1, 2, 3, ...$$

The thing is that I don't know the function $z_e(x)$ but I do know its value in the limits $x=0$ and $x=c$.

Ideas?

---

**EDIT:**
The thing is that I don't know the function $z_e(x)$, but I do know the value of that function at the limits $x=0$ and $x=c$, as well as its derivatives there.

---

**EDIT 2:**
I will add here my own try (I think it's wrong, so I'm asking for help to correct it). For $n=2$:

$$\int_0^c\left(\dfrac{\partial z_e(x)}{\partial x}\right)^2dx = \int_{z_e(0)}^{z_e(c)}\dfrac{\partial z_e(x)}{\partial x}dz_e(x) = \int_{?}^{?}d\left(\dfrac12 \dfrac{\partial z_e^2}{\partial x}\right)$$

Is this the correct path to solve my original question?

Comment: To be clear, is the integrand supposed to be $\dfrac{\partial z_e(x)}{\partial x}$? **EDIT:** I see you corrected it, thanks.

Comment: Yes. When $n=1$ it's easy for me to solve the integral, but when $n>1$ I don't know how to proceed (being $n$ a natural number: $n=1,2,3,\ldots$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \left(\frac{\partial z_e(x)}{\partial x}\right)^n$.

For general $z_e$, there is no closed formula for the integral
$\displaystyle\;I(c) = \int_0^c f(x) dx.$

However, you can use the derivatives of $z_e(x)$ at the end-points to compute $f^{(2k-1)}(x)$ for $k$ up to some $p$. You can then use [Euler-Macluarin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) to derive an approximation of $I(c)$ based on the derivatives at the end-points.

$$I(c) \approx \frac{c}{2}(f(0) + f(c))
- \sum_{k=1}^p \frac{B_{2k}c^{2k}}{(2k)!}\left[f^{(2k-1)}(c) - f^{(2k-1)}(0)\right]$$

Comment: Hey achille, thanks for your contribution. Can you take a look at my EDIT #2 in the original post, and say if that is correct or not?

Comment: Where is the $\frac{1}{\partial x }$ term?

Comment: @JosePerez I misread your expression but the one in EDIT #2 is still incorrect.

Comment: I thought so, but I wanted to know why? Can I say that $\left(\frac{\partial z_e}{\partial x}\right)^2dx=\left(\frac{\partial z_e}{\partial x}\right)dz_e$?

Comment: @JosePerez that part is okay, it is the last equality in EDIT #2 that is broken.

Comment: But $d\left(\frac12 \dfrac{\partial z_e^2}{\partial x}\right)=\frac12 d \left(2z_e\frac{\partial z_e}{\partial x}\right)=dz_e\frac{\partial z_e}{\partial x}$. Where is the wrong part? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JosePerez $$d\left(z_e\frac{\partial z_e}{\partial x}\right)
= \frac{\partial z_e}{\partial x} dz_e \color{red}{+ z_e\frac{\partial^2 z_e}{\partial x^2} dx}
$$

Comment: Ouch! Big blunder. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If all you know about $f$ is the values of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ and the derivatives there, then that is not enough to know what $\int_a^b (f'(x))^2\,dx$ is.

Consider, for example, if $a=0$, $b=1$, and $f(a)=f(b)=f'(a)=f'(b)=0$.
This may be satisfied either by the constantly zero function, in which case your integral is $0$, or by, for example $f(x)=x^2(x-1)^2$, in which case the integral is definitely *not* $0$ (actually $2/105$ according to Wolfram Alpha).

Comment: Cool Henning. It makes sense. I added a second edit to my original question. Can you take a look at it and see if it's correct what I did there? (You seem to know a lot of maths, so I say sorry in advance for whatever nonsense I might have written!)

Comment: (I corrected the expressions in the EDIT#2)